# A weird Shepherd with his sheep

Tags: logical-deduction, combinatorics

A friend of yours, a Shepherd, has some sheep in his stable and you know that he put some numbers on them from $1$ to $X$ in an order to track them down. Some day, you decided to give a visit to his farm.

After talking some nonsense, you start to wonder how many sheep there are in his farm since you cannot guess by just looking. You ask and he responds back:

"*Imagine that you choose $10$ sheep among all, and then you take all possible ternary sums of the sheep. When you do this, you will see that each sum will be different from each other for some $10$ sheep sets. However, if I had $1$ less sheep in total, you wouldn't get all distinct sums no matter which $10$ sheep you choose. That is how many sheep I have.*"

**Question:** How many sheep are there in his farm?

For example, if the Shepherd had said $5$ sheep instead of $10$, the answer would be $8$ since all subset ternary sums of $\left \{1,2,3,5,8  \right \}$ would be different than each other and you cannot do the same with $1$ less sheep.

Comment: I'm confused by the condition "if I had 1 less sheep in total, you wouldn't get all distinct sums no matter which 10 sheep you choose." If I have a set, S, and all ternary sums of S are distinct, then when I remove an element from S, all ternary sums will still be unique. If I take a 10 member subset of S, and remove a member from S, there are some 10 member subsets that will be unchanged.

Comment: @TonyRuth: If you remove an element from your chosen subset S (of 10 sheep), you must replace it with another sheep from the herd; the original 9 might still be ternary-sum unique, but the addition of the new 10th will break the rule.

Comment: Now that this has an accepted answer, what's the trick which makes it a puzzle rather than a computational task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> $114$ sheep.

Because

> I searched for the existence of sets of $10$ sheep (non-negative integers) such that they have all $3\text{-}subset\text{-}sums$ distinct. I first worked my way down looking for sets with any sheep up to a maximum of one less then a current upper bound (starting with an upper bound of 140 due to [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A036241) - see the very bottom of this answer). This actually got slower as it worked it's way down even though the space was being reduced, since there were less solutions to find at each level.
>  @elias pointed out that I could skip from a $116$ solution to the $114$ solution:
>  $\{1,6,16,30,54,72,92,112,113,114\}$
>  (while I was still searching at $114$) by subtracting $2$ from each of a previous upper bound output of $\{3,8,18,32,56,74,94,114,115,116\}$ from my solver (and that $1$ must be a member of the set being sought since we could always subtract a constant term from each sheep in any other satisfying set).
>  I then restricted my downward search to only sets containing the two sheep $1$ and $113$ to restrict the space further. I found no such solution, so finally I searched for any set containing $1$ and no number $\gt 112$, and again I found no solution. The last two searches both ran overnight on a single core.

I used this Python code:

> (Or slightly less formal variations of it. It's probably not the most efficient method - but it does not require huge amounts of memory like other approaches might):
>
> ```
> from itertools import combinations
>
> def iterSolutions(curVals, curSums, stop=0, step=-1):
>     if len(curVals) == 10:
>             yield curVals
>     else:
>             for n in range(curVals[-1]+step, stop, step):
>                     newSums = set()
>                     for c in combinations(curVals, 2):
>                             m = sum(c)+n
>                             if m in curSums or m in newSums:
>                                     break
>                             newSums.add(m)
>                     else:
>                             for solution in iterSolutions(curVals + [n], curSums|newSums, stop, step):
>                                     yield solution
> ```
>
> I first ran the solver (a bit) like this (`cm` being the largest sheep number in a set currently being sought):
>
> ```
> >>> cm = 139
> >>> while 1:
> ...     for sln in iterSolutions([cm], set([])):
> ...         print(sln)
> ...         cm -= 1
> ...         break
> ...     else:
> ...         print("No solutions found at cm = ".format(cm))
> ...         break
> ```
>
> in it's current form the above code will find the final solution within an hour, but wont find the $\{116,...,3\}$ set shown above. It will then keep searching at `cm=113` for *some very long amount of time*, find no solutions and print `No solutions found at cm = 113`. To skip using the same method, one could run the modification below instead, it will skip checks at `cm: 138-130, 127, 124, 123, 121-117,` and `115`, but it will still run for `cm=113` for just as long:
>
> ```
> >>> cm = 139
> >>> while 1:
> ...     for sln in iterSolutions([cm], set([])):
> ...         print(sln)
> ...         subtract = sln[-1] - 1
> ...         if subtract > 0:
> ...             adjustedSln = [v - subtract for v in sln]
> ...             print(adjustedSln)
> ...             cm = adjustedSln[0]
> ...         cm -= 1
> ...         break
> ...     else:
> ...         print("No solutions found at cm = ".format(cm))
> ...         break
> ```
>
> Next I searched for a set containing $1$ and $113$ like so:
>
> ```
> >>> for sln in iterSolutions([113, 1], set([]), 113, 1)
> ...     print(sln)
> ... else:
> ...     print("Done")
> ```
>
> which ran overnight, and finished, finding no solution with sheep $1$ and $113$ in the set and all others in between.
>
>  The final step was then to run it like this:
>
> ```
> >>> for sln in iterSolutions(1, set([]), 113, 1):
> ...     print(sln)
> ... else:
> ...     print("Done")
> ```
>
> which also ran overnight and found no solution with sheep $1$ in the set and all others less than $113$ - so the shepherd would have $113$ sheep if he had $1$ less sheep, hence he has $114$ sheep.

---

Reduced bounds from before I started a search...

> Greater than $8$ (well, $10$ hehe) and less than or equal to $309$

Because

> No subsets (even of cardinality $2$) of the set
>  $\{148,225,265,285,296,302,305,307,308,309\}$
>  have equal sums (source: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A096858/table))

A lower value for the upper bound is:

> $278$, since the set $\{1,2,4,8,15,28,52,96,165,278\}$ has all $120$ $3\text{-}subset\text{-}sums$ distinct.

Lowered further by @astralfenix to

> $150$ due to the existence of the set $\{1,2,3,5,8,14,25,45,82,150\}$

This can be lowered a touch to

> $140$ due to the existence of the set $\{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 14, 25, 45, 82, 140\}$
>  This is the set of the smallest $10$ non-negative integers yielded by starting with $\{1,2,3\}$ and adding the next possible integer that keeps the set distinct with all $pairwise\text{-}sums$ distinct; **and** all $3\text{-}subset\text{-}sums$ distinct (Source: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A036241))

Comment: Definitely a bug in my code then!

Comment: @JonathanAllan, can you explain, why a solution with $k$ as the larger number results the number of sheep being $k+1$? Why isn't the latter $k$ as well?

Comment: @Elias because I failed ^^

Comment: lol, don't take it seriously, your code works well at least :). so 114 is our current best, yeah?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44920/discussion-between-jonathan-allan-and-elias).

Comment: I get a lower bound of 114, assuming that one of the minimal sets for a given size begins $(1,2,3,\ldots)$ (which is true at least up to $n=9$).  With no assumptions, I get a lower bound of 87 before running out of memory.

Comment: Nice, @2012rcampion. Care to share any details about your method?

Comment: @elias Basically I just create a list of all valid sets starting with $\{1\}$, storing the pairwise and three-way sums for each set (e.g. $\{1,2,3\}$ is stored as the tuple $(\{1,2,3\},\{3,4,5\},\{6\})$).  Adding a new $x$ to a set $(s_1,s_2,s_3)$ is then just $(s_1\cup\{x\},s_2\cup(x+s_1),s_3\cup(x+s_2)\})$.  I do a sorted merge for the unions to detect duplicates.  If $s_3$ has duplicates I discard the new set; if $s_2$ has duplicates I examine the set but don't store it, since it can't be a 'seed' for a new set.  I add larger $x$ until $|s_1|\ge 10$ or I run out of memory.

Comment: @2012rcampion I'm not sure how is this different from the idea behind the method of JonathanAllan. Though it must be a more efficient implementation, if you have reached this conclusion by scanning through all the possibilities up to 114.

Comment: @elias Jonathan's is a depth-first search that searches from large $x$ downward; mine is a breadth-first search that searches from small $x$ upward.

Comment: I still cannot see the difference between 'from large $x$ downward' and 'from small $x$ upward' because of the problem being invariant for linearity. And I'm a little bit confused also about why a breadth-first approach finishes much faster than a depth-first does. Maybe it's my shortsightedness, but maybe a basic difference in your implementations. Were you doing it with Mathematica, @2012rcampion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44940/discussion-between-2012rcampion-and-elias).

Comment: The description of the OEIS sequence (currently the last spoiler block) is wrong. What it should say is that this is the output of a greedy search which always adds the smallest number to the set without breaking the distinctness properties.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Actually the description is fine on OIES since it defines the elements in terms of existing elements. I updated my description though.

Answer (score -2):

Is it related to pattern recognition. Because I think it's not that straight forward. Still I wanna try

> {1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89}
> Answer is 89

EDIT: Since I know that I am wrong. Here is my second attempt

> Till 5 numbers it was alright to follow the fibonacci series. But as soon as we require a 6th number then the logic fails because in fibonacci series (T1 + T2) + T6 = T3 + (T4 + T5). So I've to try out a different logic henceforth. 
>  So I thought, if our new number is greater than the sum of the max 3 values, then It will suffice So I concluded that the 6th number must be > 16(3+5+8) and hence it must be 17. So I got a new sequence : {1,2,3,5,8,17,31,57,106,195}.
>  But still, I was not convinced, I wanted to optimise it further. Let's assume the 6th number is X. So what we really need to achieve is (X+1+2) > (3,5,8) => X>13 => X=14 since we want smallest. Therefore moving further with rest of the remaining numbers I got another sequence : {1,2,3,5,8,14,25,45,82,150}.

Still optimising it, I guess there exists a better solution

Comment: Nope. 1+2+13 = 8+5+3

Comment: Ohh that way... got ur point, will update shortly

Comment: OK guys I got my mistake... should I remove this post to avoid any downvotes ??

Comment: Maybe you should edit it, adding how you arrived to this conclusion, and that you are aware it is not the correct solution. I think it can be turned into a good answer, as it was my first idea, and I've also seen it from other users before, so if you manage to turn it into an 'avoid this pitfall' kind of message, it can be helpful.